# Disable text selection on chrome/firefox reading view

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, textselection

I recently opened a blog and I'm having some issues with my articles: I'm trying to make it ''impossibile'' to copy them elsewhere.
I've already used the standard CSS code to disable text selection

```
.post-content {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none; 
}
```

But as soon as I open the reading view, it stops working.
I've already tried to search for a solution, but I found nothing.
Is there a way?

Comment: Actually there is no any complete solution to this, because you are serving the content in your html markup therefore visitors can copy them easily by setting css or javascript disabled in their browser or by inspecting your web page which let them to copy everything from loaded content.

Comment: You can try to add your text inside a canvas or publish your work as image. or just agree with that if you put it out there it will be copied ;)

Comment: Try applying these events on the body or a div tag that contains all the text. `onmousedown='return false;' onselectstart='return false;'`. Then maybe disable right-click on the page. It's just a hack though

Comment: Thank you all very much. I hoped there was at least some way to stop the reader view of chrome/mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to actually prevent a user from copying your content from a technical point of view. A user can change all the client-side code (view) once access has been granted to him.

Once the content has been placed and users have access to it, there's pretty much nothing you can do other than take legal action when the content ends up somewhere else where it's not supposed to be.